# Is AS2 versions backwards compatible?

Tags: network-protocols

Is AS2 version 1.2 compatible with version 1.1? If I'm sending messages from system using version 1.2 to a system that only supports version 1.1 will the message get delivered ok? Messages would be sent to both directions.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to depend upon the software vendor's implementation and whether or not they had it drummond certified.  I am having a problem right now because my system only supports up to AS2 version 1.1  My trading partner is complaining that his system is not accepting my transmissions because they are missing certain headers.  When I researched the headers, they are new to AS2.